# Custom URL for Wagtail model

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a model like this:

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page

class Blog(Page):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ...
    ..
```

Right Now, my default, if my slug is `hi-there`, the blog post is accessible on `site_url:/hi-there/` but I want it accessible via `site:url/2014/02/05/hi-there/` The page has various methods like `url, url_path` which one should I override and what's the best practice to achieve something like this in wagtail?

Answer (score 6):

The [RoutablePageMixin](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/reference/contrib/routablepage.html) is  the current (v2.0+) way to accomplish this.

Add the module to your installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...

   "wagtail.contrib.routable_page",
]
```

Inherit from both `wagtail.contrib.routable_page.models.RoutablePageMixin` and `wagtail.core.models.Page`, then define some view methods and decorate them with the `wagtail.contrib.routable_page.models.route` decorator:

```
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.contrib.routable_page.models import RoutablePageMixin, route

class EventPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    ...

    @route(r'^$') # will override the default Page serving mechanism
    def current_events(self, request):
        """
        View function for the current events page
        """
        ...

    @route(r'^past/$')
    def past_events(self, request):
        """
        View function for the past events page
        """
        ...

    # Multiple routes!
    @route(r'^year/(\d+)/$')
    @route(r'^year/current/$')
    def events_for_year(self, request, year=None):
        """
        View function for the events for year page
        """
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

New in Wagtail v0.5 is a mechanism that directly addresses this sort of thing:

[Embedding URL configuration in Pages](http://wagtail.readthedocs.org/en/v0.5/core_components/pages/advanced_topics/routable_page.html#embedding-url-configuration-in-pages) or [RoutablePage](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.3.1/reference/contrib/routablepage.html) in v1.3.1

(the docs even have an Blog example!)

Comment: But I should override url method or something right? Because the page url would still yield the default url?

Comment: The above link is no longer valid - an up-to-date URL is http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.3/reference/contrib/routablepage.html

Answer (score 2):

I was looking into migrating my blog to a wagtail version and wanted to support my previous url schema and had to solve this exact problem. Luckily I just found a solution and want to share it, hopefully this will be helpful for someone else in the future.

The solution is a 2 Step process.

1. change the url of a blog page to contain the date as well.

```
class Blog(Page):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_url_parts(self, request=None):
        super_response = super().get_url_parts(request)
        # handle the cases of the original implementation
        if super_response is None:
            return None
        (site_id, root_url, page_path) = super_response
        if page_path == None:
            return super_response

        # In the happy case, add the date fields
        # split prefix and slug to support blogs that are nested
        prefix, slug, _ = page_path.rsplit("/", 2)
        return (
            site_id,
            root_url,
            f"{prefix}/{self.created.year}/{self.created.month}/{self.created.day}/{slug}/",
        )
```

2. And now we need to make those posts also route-able.

```
class BlogIndexPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    ...
    def route(self, request, path_components):
        if len(path_components) >= 4:
            year, month, day, slug, *rest = path_components
            try:
                subpage = self.get_children().get(slug=slug)
                return subpage.specific.route(request, rest)
            except Page.DoesNotExist:
                ...
        return super().route(request, path_components)
```

This solution ignores the date and just use the slug to locate a blog post as the original solution. This should also work when you don't use the `RoutablePageMixin`.

Hope this is still helpful for someone.