# How to define Blog Post URL in Wagtail?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm trying to write a simple blog in Wagtail and wondering how I can define a different URL scheme for blog posts detail view. I have a model like this:

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = StreamField([
        ('rich_text', blocks.RichTextBlock(icon='doc-full', label='Rich Text')),
        ('html', blocks.RawHTMLBlock(icon='site', label='HTML'))
    ])

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + (
        index.SearchField('intro'),
        index.SearchField('body')
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro'),
        StreamFieldPanel('body')
    ]
```

With this the url of a single blog post is `/blog/[slug]`. What I'd like to achieve is urls with year and month, like `/blog/2015/12/[slug]`.

I found the `RoutablePageMixin` but I don't really understand if this is the right tool and how to use it in my case.

Comment: I don't have the full answer, but look into `promote_panels[]`. You may be able to pass a default somehow to `FieldPanel('slug')`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240599/custom-url-for-wagtail-model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom URL for Wagtail model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240599/custom-url-for-wagtail-model)